# How to make 1-100 score out of two datasets in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have two datasets:

1) The number of days passed since the product was released
2) Total Number of Positive Reviews

What I am trying to archive is a 1-100 score, since the product that was released one year ago and has +1000 positive reviews is not the same with a product that was released a 1-2 month ago and already has +300 positive reviews. In a nutshell, depending on "days passed till now" - the value of "total amount of positive reviews" should drop giving 1-100 rating to filter out the most valuable products.

I'm not even sure how to approach this problem, please help me out.

There would be around 1000 products that I'd need to score, so I thought there might be a predefined formula for this in Google Sheets.

Example: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y3q7URy5s8B5x3HVIzjaDzIZN3FRRvoduJAXobw1UOk/edit#gid=1382498268

Comment: Here it is: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y3q7URy5s8B5x3HVIzjaDzIZN3FRRvoduJAXobw1UOk/edit#gid=1382498268

Comment: Unfortunately, it needs to be a lot more complex. Depending on "days passed till now" - the value of "total amount of positive reviews" should drop giving 1-100 rating to filter out the most valuable products.

Comment: It'll be hard as I'm not sure how much the number of days should lower total positive review to put into 1-100 score because I can't keep so much data to compare it in my head.

Answer (score 0):

**this will filter out all products with:**

- 1000+ reviews if older than 356 days
- 300+ reviews if not older than 60 days

---

```
={A1:D1; QUERY(
 {IFERROR(QUERY(A2:D, "select * where D >= 1000 and C > 365", 0), {"","","",""});
  IFERROR(QUERY(A2:D, "select * where D >= 300 and C < 60 ", 0), {"","","",""})},
 "select * order by Col4 desc", 0)}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**if you still want that "score" column use this:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 {{QUERY(A2:D, "select A where C >= 365 order by D desc", 0),
   ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(
   QUERY(A2:D, "select A where C >= 365 order by D", 0))))};
  {QUERY(A2:D, "select A where C < 365 and C > 0 order by D desc", 0),
   ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(
   QUERY(A2:D, "select A where C < 365 and C > 0 order by D", 0))))}},
 2, 0), ))
```

[image]

**if you want no more then 100 use:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 {{QUERY(A2:D, "select A where C >= 365 order by D desc", 0),
   ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(
   QUERY(A2:D, "select A where C >= 365 order by D", 0))))};
  {QUERY(A2:D, "select A where C < 365 and C > 0 order by D desc", 0),
   ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(
   QUERY(A2:D, "select A where C < 365 and C > 0 order by D", 0))))}},
 2, 0), )>100, ,
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, 
 {{QUERY(A2:D, "select A where C >= 365 order by D desc", 0),
   ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(
   QUERY(A2:D, "select A where C >= 365 order by D", 0))))};
  {QUERY(A2:D, "select A where C < 365 and C > 0 order by D desc", 0),
   ROW(INDIRECT("A1:A"&COUNTA(
   QUERY(A2:D, "select A where C < 365 and C > 0 order by D", 0))))}},
 2, 0), )))
```

Comment: thank you but that's not what I have been asking for but I'm sure for some people it will resolve their issue. I just hired someone to complete this task for me.